# componentDidUpdate() is not firing when component is wrapped in HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I have HOC component which wraps all the page Components. The page component has pagination, when user clicks next, the route params changes and the difference between route param and state is compared in componentDidUpdate and then api is called. The code works on without wrapping HOC.

#### Routes

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import hocWrapper from './hocWrapper'
import Dashboard from './components/screens/dashboard/Dashboard';
import Movies from './components/screens/movies/Movies';
const Routes = (props) => (
    <Switch style={{ position: 'absolute' }}>
        <Route exact path="/all/page:pageNumber" component={hocWrapper(Dashboard)} />
        <Route exact path="/movies/page:pageNumber" component={Movies} />
    </Switch>
);
export default withRouter(Routes);
```

#### HOC wrapper Component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { searchTextAction } from './containers/actions/userActions'
export default function (ComposedClass) {
    const ClosedRouteForUser = (props) => {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log(window.location.pathname)
            if (window.location.pathname !== `/search/page1` &&
                window.location.pathname.includes('details') === false) {
                dispatch(searchTextAction(''))
            }
        }, []);
        return <ComposedClass {...props} />;
    };
    return ClosedRouteForUser;
}
```

#### Page Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import apiCall from '../../../services/apiCall';
import { trendingURL } from '../../../services/apiURL'
import MediaList from '../../common/MediaList'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
class Dashboard extends Component {

    state = {
        dataList: [],
        refresh: false,
        pageNumber: this.props.match?.params && this.props.match.params.pageNumber,
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            if (this.props.match?.params.routedFrom) {
                localStorage.setItem("routedFrom", this.props.match.params.routedFrom)
            }
            console.log('cd mount')
            window.scrollTo(0, 0)
            this.setState({ refresh: true })
            let data = { page: 1, media_type: "all" }
            let apiData = await apiCall(trendingURL, data)
            this.setState({ dataList: apiData.results, refresh: false })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

    }

    async componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.props.match.params.pageNumber !== this.state.pageNumber) {
            console.log('cd updates')
            let data = { page: this.props.match.params.pageNumber, media_type: "all" }
            let apiData = await apiCall(trendingURL, data)
            this.setState({
                dataList: apiData.results,
                pageNumber: this.props.match.params.pageNumber,
                refresh: false
            })

        }
    }

    pageNavigate = (value) => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
        this.setState({ pageNumber: value })
        this.props.history.replace({ pathname: `/all/page${value}` })
    }

    previous = () => {
        this.pageNavigate(parseInt(this.props.match.params.pageNumber) - 1)
    }
    next = () => {
        this.pageNavigate(parseInt(this.props.match.params.pageNumber ?
            this.props.match.params.pageNumber :
            1) + 1)
    }

    render() {
        const { dataList, refresh } = this.state
        return (
            <MediaList
                listData={dataList}
                refresh={refresh}
                previous={this.previous}
                next={this.next}
            />
        )
    }
}
export default withRouter(Dashboard)
```